# What is the best alternative for Google Satellite Map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show **free** satellite images in **offline** mode for Android devices. But currently google maps is not free. Does anyone have suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapbox is their it's integration is also easy